# lowtilde option for URL package

Tags: urls

[edited to correct confusion over paths]

My Mac version of latex includes two versions of `url.sty` --- one is from 2006 and supports `[lowtilde]` while the other is from 1999 and does not:

```
$ grep 'ver ' /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf/tex/latex/html/url.sty
% url.sty  ver 1.4    02-Mar-1999   Donald Arseneau   asnd@triumf.ca
  \ProvidesPackage{url}[1999/03/02 \space ver 1.4 \space
% url.sty  ver 1.4   02-Mar-1999   Donald Arseneau   asnd@reg.triumf.ca
% characters.  The "\url" command will *never ever* hyphenate words.
% command follows whatever the currently-set style dictates.
% I.e., using whatever url-style has been selected.
% ver 1.1 6-Feb-1996: 
% ver 1.2 19-Oct-1996:
% ver 1.3 21-Jul-1997:
% ver 1.4 02-Mar-1999
$ grep 'ver '  /usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty
% url.sty  ver 3.3    12-Apr-2006   Donald Arseneau   asnd@triumf.ca
 {url}[2006/04/12 \space ver 3.3 \space Verb mode for urls, etc.]
% url.sty  ver 3.3    12-Apr-2006   Donald Arseneau   asnd@triumf.ca
% characters.  The "\url" command will *never ever* hyphenate words.
% command follows whatever the currently-set style dictates.
% I.e., using whatever "\urlstyle" and other settings are already in effect.
% ver 1.1 6-Feb-1996:
% ver 1.2 19-Oct-1996:
% ver 1.3 21-Jul-1997:
% ver 1.4 02-Mar-1999:
% ver 1.5 28-Mar-1999:
% ver 1.6 20-Jun-2002:
% ver 3.0 June 2003/Nov 2003:
% ver 3.1 Mar 2004:
% ver 3.2 June 2005:
% ver 3.3 April 2006:
$
```

Why are two versions installed and how to I specify the correct version?

Comment: TeX Live2011 and TeX Live2010 use version ver 3.3 (2006/04/12) of `url.sty`, and the `lowtilde` option can be used with this version. What exactly do you mean with "does not support"?

Comment: Ah. It seems that my Mac installation installes two `url.sty` files, one in `texmf/tex/laytex/html/url.sty` and one in `texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty`. The first is from 1999 and does not have the option. Why are there two and how do I get the proper one?

Comment: You should not have the one located in `/texmf/tex/latex`. I would suggest deleting it, and then rerunning `texhash` (or refreshing your filename database via `tlmgr`).

Comment: But that one was installed by the Mac PDF installer!!!

Comment: MacTeX doesn't install a `tex/latex/html` subdirectory under `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf`. So it must have been installed by some other program.

Comment: You are right. I completely deleted my install and did a reinstall. Perhaps it was installed by texlive 2010. In any event, if you change your comment to a an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks.

Comment: @vy32 Done; note that you need to add `@name` when directing comments other than to the question or answer contributor, or they won't get informed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MacTeX doesn't install a `tex/latex/html` subdirectory under `/usr/local/texlive/2011/texmf`. So it must have been installed by some other program (probably some TeX to HTML converter you installed via a `Makefile`).